# Getting variables from Scapy using Python

Tags: python, scapy

Hi I need help trying to access elements in what seems to be a tuple that scapy is returning. The code is below.

```
ans,unans=sr(IP(dst="www.google.com",ttl=5)/ICMP(),verbose=0)
ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.src%") )
```

If I enter Scapy and type both of these commands manually it will return a single IP address. However I am running it from inside a Python script and need to store that IP address as a variable. This may be a stupid question and I am just learning Scapy, but how would I store this IP address as a variable using scapy? I am wanting to achieve something like the below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *
ans,unans=sr(IP(dst="www.google.com",ttl=5)/ICMP(),verbose=0)
SourceIP = ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.src%") )
```

Comment: Why didn't what you did work? What error did you get, or what result did you get that you didn't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever need the value of a layer use the getlayer method. So just change things to:

```
ans = sr1(IP(dst="www.google.com",ttl=5)/ICMP(),verbose=0)
address = ans.getlayer(IP).src
```

There is also another method to if a layer exists that returns true or false. Here is an example of that one.

```
if ans.haslayer(IP):
    print "Packet has the layer IP"
```