# How to get scapy IP address list result from sr function into a variable

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to do an ICMP (host is alive scan) in a range of ip addresses with the use of scapy.
But i want to store the result list from the sr function( only the answers ) at a variable so that i can use it for some other purpose. But it does not seem to work.
**I tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371310/getting-variables-from-scapy-using-python) but it does not work in my case, cause the expected result is a list of IP's and i want to store and display later all of them.**

If i enter scapy and type the above commands it works fine!

```
ans,_ = sr(IP(dst='192.168.1.1-7')/ICMP(), timeout=10)
ans.summary( lambda s_r: s_r[1].sprintf("{IP: %IP.src% is alive}"))
```

The result that gives me :

```
 192.168.1.1 is alive
 192.168.1.3 is alive
 192.168.1.5 is alive
 192.168.1.6 is alive
```

This is what i tried(in my pycharm project) but it gives the error **'tuple' object has no attribute 'getlayer'**

```
ips = '192.168.1.1-9'
ans, _ = sr(IP(dst=ips) / ICMP(), timeout=10)
address = ans.getlayer(IP).src
print(address)
```

Comment: Please make your question clear, it's barely understandable. "It doesn't work": what doesn't work ?! "works at the scapy framework" ?! Please use proper, well formatted english (too much bold..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ans_ips = [a[1].src for a in ans]
```